# How to use a wildcard for a higher-kinded type in Scala?

Tags: scala, wildcard, higher-kinded-types

Let's say I have this trait

```
trait Ctx[C, V[_]]
```

I am unable to construct any method signature that takes a Ctx of which the second type parameter is unspecified (wildcard). E.g. this:

```
def test(c: Ctx[_, _]) = ()
```

doesn't compile (`"error: _$2 takes no type parameters, expected: one"`). Neither can I do

```
def test(c: Ctx[_, _[_]]) = ()
```

(`"error: _$2 does not take type parameters"`). What am I missing?

Comment: You may have found a bug with existential types here.  I'd check the trac database and read the existential types section in the Scala Language Specification to make sure that higher-kinded existential types are possible.

Comment: I updated my answer - may be the latest revision can be helpful.

Comment: @jsuereth http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/2308 (I think higher kinds existential is related to higher kinds wildcard). The whole bug report is interesting.

Comment: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8039

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm able to define this one:

```
def test[V[X]](c:Ctx[_,V]) {}
```

And it seems to work ok with type inference:

```
scala> trait Ctx[ C, V[ _ ]]
defined trait Ctx

scala> def test[V[X]](c:Ctx[_,V]) {}
test: [V[X]](c: Ctx[_, V])Unit

scala> class P extends Ctx[Int, List]
defined class P

scala> new P
res0: P = P@1f49969

scala> test(res0)
```

**Edit**: I suspect it won't be practical to replace `Ctx` to use an abstract type, but this is what I was able to do:

```
trait Ctx[C] { type V[X] }
class CtxOption[C] extends Ctx[C] { type V[X] = Option[X] }
class CtxList[C] extends Ctx[C] { type V[X] = List[X] }

def test(ctx:Ctx[_]) { println(ctx) }

val ctxOptInt = new CtxOption[Int]
val ctxListStr = new CtxList[String]

test(ctxOptInt)
test(ctxListStr)

val list = collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Ctx[_]]()
list += ctxOptInt
list += ctxListStr
list
```

Using an abstract type for *V* spares you the complicated (or impossible) task of figuring the type parameter syntax for a wildcard type constructor. Additionally as demonstrated in the *ListBuffer* example you can then handle objects where the `V` is a different type constructor (*Option* and *List* in my example). The first solution I provided would not allow you to do that.

**Edit 2**: How about?

```
trait AbstractCtx[C] { type W[X] }
trait Ctx[C,V[_]] extends AbstractCtx[C] { type W[X] = V[X] }
def test(ctx:AbstractCtx[_]) { println(ctx) }
```

Comment: ok, so i need to use generics. i just wonder why that is, as i don't need them for first-order types... i still hope there is a way to express _[_] somehow, but this is at least a viable workaround.

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass a type constructor for the second argument of `Ctx`. Scala is not able to infer the correct kind if you just pass `_`. Neither is it possible to define a type constructor with wildcards (i.e. `_[_]]` on the fly. Note that in your first example `_$2` in the error message refers to the type passed as second argument to `Ctx` as a whole. In the second example however `_$2` refers to the the first wildcard type in `_[_]`. See the location indicator in the error messages:

```
<console>:6: error: _$2 does not take type parameters
       def test( c: Ctx[ _, _[ _ ]]) {}
                            ^
```

The following works since here `V` is a type constructor of the right kind expected by `Ctx`.

```
def test[V[_]]( c: Ctx[ _, V]) {}
```